# A decoder-based keypad

Tags: digital-logic

This is the design for a 5 x 5 keyboard SIMULATION that I have created, but it is not working.

The encoder doesn't get a low signal when I press a button. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Fix the schematic first: (1) Add GND symbols where possible to eliminate unnecessary traces. (2) Fix the traces that are running across the bottom edges of your chips. (3) Straighten out the unnecessary corners, crossings and dots to the left of U5. (4) Your circuit has no power. If it is powered then show it. (5) Fix the mess to the right of U3. Move U3 down so that at least one of the key matrix wires can go straight in. (6) Fix the diagonal line to the left of U10. It can go directly to the vertical line on the left. (7) Turn off the grid before taking a screengrab.

Comment: (8) "*... but it is not working.*" Is this a simulation or a real circuit? Put all the info into your question and not in the comments.

Comment: @Transistor thank you, for making me clean it up, think it is fixed. There was an unnecessary node.

Comment: Good. You can post the updated schematic as an answer. It may be helpful to someone else. Mention what simulator you're using. Finally, you can accept your own answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

There was an unnecessary node, here is a cleaner Proteus schematic for a 5x5 keypad circuit that (i think) should work. All the input of the encoder can be NANDed to detect a button press which can be used to record the decoder inputs (column number) and the encoder outputs (row number).

NOTE: The encoder pins that are grounded (except the enable pin) were supposed to be at 5V.

[image]

Comment: Good work - although you did forget to turn off the grid. Good schematics are an art but one of the things to remember is that you are communicating a "scheme". Your revised layout reads nicely from left to right with positive power at the top and ground at the bottom. As you have discovered it also avoids errors and facilitates debugging. Keep it up.

Comment: @Transistor - thanks for your help, i will keep that in mind.

Comment: @DumbDude Could you give the part references of the decoders? I'm interrested.